# Integral with respect of $(dW_s)^n$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I know
$$\int _0^t dW_s=W_t-W_0=W_t$$
Since $ dW_s dW_s=ds$ ,  so
$$\int _0^t( dW_s)^2=\int_0^t ds=t-0=t$$
I Want to know why for $n\ge 3$ we have
 $$\int _0^t (dW_s)^n=0$$
**My try**
$$(dW_s)^2 dW_s (dW_s)^{n-3}=ds dW_s (dW_s)^{n-3}
=0$$
Is it true? What is relation between Ito Integarl and varation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true, but your solution is meaningless.Let $I=\{t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_m\}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$ and $\delta_m=\max\{t_{i+1}-t_{i}\}_{i=0}^{m}\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$. For $n=3$, we have

$$\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3\Big|\le\underset{0\le i\le m-1}{\mathop{\max }}\Big|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}\Big|\cdot\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^2\Big|\tag 1$$

Since  the sample path of Wiener process is continues, thus
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\underset{0\le i\le m-1}{\mathop{\max }}\Big|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}\Big|=0\tag 2$$

Moreover

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^2\Big|=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^2=t<\infty\tag 3$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ and $(3)$

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3\Big|=\Big|\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3\Big|\le 0$$
therefore
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3=0$$
In other words
$$\int_{0}^{t}(dW_s)^3=0$$
Let the theorem is true for $n=k$, $k>3$, i.e
$$\int_{0}^{t}(dW_s)^k=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^k=0\tag 4$$

For $n=k+1$, we have

$$\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^{k+1}\Big|\le\underset{0\le i\le m-1}{\mathop{\max }}\Big|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}\Big|\cdot\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^{k}\Big|\tag 5$$

$(2)$ and $(4)$ and $(5)$

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\Big|\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^{k+1}\Big|=\Big|\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^{k+1}\Big|\le 0$$ 
In other words
$$\int_{0}^{t}(dW_s)^{k+1}=0$$

> The theorem was proved by mathematical induction.

Comment: Thanks. Why $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})^n= \int _{0}^t (dW_s)^n$

Comment: By definition of $n-th$ Variation of Wiener process.

Comment: What is relation between the defintion of varation and Ito integral?

Comment: Please check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus